# My onOpen trigger is running only half of the script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script `onOpen` is running only half of the script. When I try to run the scrip manually it works, but when I refresh the spreadsheet, it only changes the number to 5 in cell A10.

```
 function onOpen() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const rok = ss.getSheetByName('ROK');
  const id = ss.getSheetByName('ID');
  const kontrola = rok.getRange('I4').getValue();
   ss.getSheetByName('DATA').getRange('A10').setValue(5)
  
  if (kontrola == 1) {
  //iGV synergie copy
    const term = rok.getRange('G3').getValue();
    const name = ('iGV'+term);
    const Synergie = id.getRange('C5').getValue();
    const iGVSarchiveid = id.getRange('C3').getValue();
    const iGVSarchive = DriveApp.getFolderById(iGVSarchiveid);
    const iGVS = DriveApp.getFolderById(Synergie).getFilesByName('iGVxF&L');
    const copyiGVS = iGVS.next().makeCopy(name);
    const urlcopyiGVS = copyiGVS.getUrl();
    DriveApp.getFilesByName(name).next().moveTo(iGVSarchive);
    ss.getSheetByName('DATA').getRange('J3').setValue(urlcopyiGVS)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Issue:**

The issue is that you are using a simple `onOpen` trigger which according to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) has the following restriction which is relevant to your case:

> Simple triggers cannot access services that require authorization. For
> example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail
> service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a
> phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.

Essentially the simple trigger can not access `DriveApp` because it requires authorization to do so.

---

### **Solution:**

Create an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onOpen` trigger instead. Rename your function and use any name except for `onOpen` and then go to your current project's triggers and create an installable trigger for your function (in my example `myFunction`):

```
 function myFunction() {
// code goes here
}
```

[image: example]